# ProxyPassMatch rule for Symfony 2.4

Tags: apache, symfony, php

I am running Apache using mod_proxy_fcgi and PHP-FPM and am trying to get it to work Symfony.  This is my first project using Symfony and am just getting a feel for it at the moment..

My vhost definition currently looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName symfony.dev
  Documentroot "/vagrant/symfony/web"
  DirectoryIndex app.php

  ProxyTimeout 600
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:5090/vagrant/symfony/web/$1

  <Directory "/vagrant/symfony/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `http://symfony.dev/app_dev.php/`, the page loads, but all the links/paths include the full filesystem page. For example, the link for "Run the demo" is `http://symblog.dev/vagrant/symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/`.

Is there a different ProxyPassMatch rule that would work, or a Symfony config that can compensate?

I tried `^/(.*\.php)(/.*)?$` which gets `app_dev.php/` to load, but then `app_dev.php/demo/` seems to load `app_dev.php` and not the demo, with broken paths to inline resources.

Comment: Were you able to solve that? I am having the same issue

Comment: The fault is with PHP FPM where the usual set of $_SERVER variables are not correctly set according to the standard.  The work around is to set these variables yourself, before HttpFoundation/Request is constructed.  Right now I'm not completely sure which variables need to be set (SCRIPT_FILENAME, and/or PATH_INFO) or the best place to modify them in a Symfony project (in AppKernel.php?).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with ProxyPassMatch, but with  and SetHandler everything works fine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project.dev
   ServerAlias www.project.dev


   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
   </FilesMatch>

   #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/web/$1

   ## Vhost docroot
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/project/web"

   ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/awesome
   <Directory "/var/www/project/web">
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from All
   </Directory>

   ## Load additional static includes

   ## Logging
   ErrorLog "/var/www/project/app/logs/apache2/error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/www/project/app/logs/apache2/access.log" combined

   ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
   SetEnv APP_ENV dev

   ## Custom fragment
 </VirtualHost>
```